# Create .a file instead .so using android studio?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-studio

How to create **.a** file instead **.so** from c source using android studio?

If it is possible , then also I want want to know how to load them and pros and cons of using .a file instead .so

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: I read that c source can be compiled in also .a  file and read more on it, how both work differently on other systems,but did not find any resources for android system.Purpose is experimenting for now.

Answer (score 2):

Android relies on Java's [`System.loadLibrary()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)) to load native code. This call uses the [`dl*` family of functions](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen) to load a dynamic library (commonly associated with extension `.so`).
The dynamic library can specify other libraries as its dependencies, which will be loaded in turn.
After opening the library, the JVM probes it for functions with specially crafted names, which are bound to the corresponding Java methods.

By contrast, a `.a` file is a static library. It is simply an archive of object files (`.o`) that are meant for consumption by **static** linking when compilation.

To answer your question: yes, you could alter your CMakeLists.txt to create static libraries, but *eventually* you will have to link these together into a dynamic .so in order to load it in Android. See for example the bottom part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41893129/1548468) where a number of prebuilt static libraries are linked together with a single `.cpp` file to produce a dynamic library.